# Mercurial annotate --include not finding files

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to to get Mercurial's annotate command to work on files specifed by an include pattern. When I run the test batch file below,

```
hg annotate --include *.txt
```

gives me the following error:

```
abort: at least one filename or pattern is required
```

As you can see, I'm using the same pattern to add the files to the repo, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Appreciate any help.

Batch file:

```
mkdir merc_test
hg init merc_test
cd merc_test
echo "1" > 1.txt
echo "2" > 2.txt
hg add --include *.txt
hg commit -m "checking in"
hg annotate 1.txt
hg annotate --include *.txt
cd ..
rmdir /s /q merc_test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `--include *.txt` is an option, but you still need a file argument at the end.  Try this

```
hg annotate --include `*.txt` .
```

That trailing period is the non-option filename.

Also, make sure to quote the *.txt part because if you have a .txt file in your current dir your shell will expand it and the pattern won't do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, it makes more sense when you think of how a --exclude would work in the absence of a trailing pattern, but the error message sucks.